# Olympiad minimum question, minimal value

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If the numbers $A, B, C$ are such that the expression $\sqrt{A-B} + \sqrt{(B+3)^2} + C^2 - 4C + 4$ is as small as possible, then $A+B+C$ is?

I thought start with,

$A > B > C$ without loss of generality. Then apply AM-GM:

$$\frac{\sqrt{A-B} + B + 3 + C^2 - 4C + 4}{6} \ge \sqrt[6]{\sqrt{A-B}\cdot B \cdot 3 \cdot C^2 \cdot 4C \cdot 4} = (A-B)^{1/12}\cdot $$

Nevermind, that doesnt work. Any Ideas?

Comment: To minimize the first term, A=B, right?

Comment: Make each term $\sqrt{A-B},\sqrt{(B+3)^2},C^2 - 4C + 4 = (C-2)^2$ equal $0$.

Comment: That's definitely **with** loss of generality. You need the whole problem to be symmetric in order to do that, not just the value you want to find.

Answer (score 4):

since $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$

so is $\sqrt{(B+3)^2}$, minimum at $B=-3$, similarly for the first term we get $A=B=-3$

For the subsequent part in $C$ use completing the square to arive at $(C-2)^2$

we know, $x^2 \ge 0$ so $C=2$

Thus, $A+B+C=-3+-3+2=-4$

Answer (score 3):

It can be written as
$$\sqrt{A-B}+|B+3|+(C-2)^2\ge 0$$
and the zero is clearly achieved only for $C-2=0, B+3=0, A=B$, which gives $A+B+C=-4$.

Comment: You mean A = -3?

Comment: @Mark, I think he means, $A=3$ because of $|B + 3|$